# How to remove multiple blocks of Gutenberg at the same time?

Tags: block-editor

Currently, I have to remove one block per time.

How to remove multiple blocks of Gutenberg at the same time?

Comment: This is a forum for WP coding & development questions, not it's general use. Or were you asking for how to remove blocks from being available in the editor? In which case you should edit your question to be more specific and show the code you've tried that's not working for you.

Comment: @PeterHvD, thank you for the negative feedback. However, this question was very well answered below, solving the doubt and broadening the knowledge base for similar future questions, which is the purpose of the StackExchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click and drag mouse out of a block, to select multiple ones - but it's not very comfortable option, IMHO (especially when there are large blocks).

Another way is to click one block, then press shift (and hold it) and and click another block - all blocks between them will get selected.